# Finding farmers markets from zip codes or town names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a small project where the user enters a zip code or town name and the computer outputs all farmer's market's that are in that zip code or town name.

I have a function that turns markets.txt (a txt which includes state, zipcode, town, city, name of farmers market) into 2 dictionaries: one that maps zip codes to farmers market tuples and another that maps towns to zip codes. My main program first checks if the user input is a zip code or if it is a town name and then (if the user gives a zip code) takes a list of all zip codes and finds a farmers market tuple to then format for readability as an output. In the case that it is a town, it's largely the same except the function retrieves a zip code from the user input town name to then get farmer's market tuples and format it.

I'm looking through markets.txt however and there are multiple farmer's markets for town names (such as this town called Granville) but the program only prints 1 rather than all of them.

Thanks so much!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
def read_markets(filename):
    """
    Read in the farmers market data from the file named filename and return 
    a tuple of two objects:
    1) A dictionary mapping zip codes to lists of farmers market tuples.
    2) A dictionary mapping towns to sets of zip codes.
    """
 
 
 
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.strip().split('#')
 
            #print(type(s[4]))
          #  s[4] are zipcodes, s[3] are towns, s[:4] is state, name, address, city
            d1[s[4]] = (s[:4])
            d2[s[3]] = (s[4])
            #print(s[:4])
        return d1, d2
 
 
def print_market(market):
    """
    Returns a string representing the farmers market tuple
    passed to the market parameter.
    """
    #input is market tuple
    name = market[1]
    address = market[2]
    city = market[3]
    state = market[0]
    zcode = (list(d1.keys())[list(d1.values()).index(market)])
    final = name + "\n" + address + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + zcode
    #print(final)
    return final
 #   print(b)
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # This main program first reads in the markets.txt once (using the function read_markets
    # and then asks the user repeatedly to enter a zip code or
    # a town name (in a while loop until the user types "quit").
 
    FILENAME = "markets.txt"
    c = 0
 
    try: 
        zip_to_market, town_to_zips = read_markets(FILENAME)
        while c < 1:
            u_in = input("enter zip code or town name: ")
            if u_in == "quit":
                c = 1
            else:
                #check if its a zip code
                if u_in.isdigit():
                    print("Ok, I will look for farmers markets matching that zipcode")
                    askzip = str(u_in)
                    #list of all zipcodes
                    mlist = d1.keys()
                    #look for corresponding zipcode in dictionary that maps zipcodes to market tuples
                    if askzip in mlist:
                        out1 = d1.get(askzip)
                        print(print_market(out1))
                    else:
                        print('No corresponding farmers markets exist for that zipcode')
                #user input is town name
                else:
                    print("Ok, I will look for farmers markets in that town")
                    asktown = str(u_in)
                    tlist = d2.keys()
                    if asktown in tlist:
                        outzip = d2.get(asktown)
                        #print(outzip)
                        #we got zip from our dictionary mapping zip codes to town names so now 
                        mlist = d1.keys()
                        if outzip in mlist:
                           # print(outzip)
                            out1 = d1.get(outzip)
                            print(print_market(out1))
                    else:
                        print('No corresponding farmers markets exist for that town name')
 
 
 
 
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError): 
        print("Error reading {}".format(FILENAME))
 
#testing things 
#read_markets("markets.txt")
#market = ['Wyoming', 'Wyoming Fresh Market', '121 W 15th Street', 'Cheyenne']
#print_market(market)
```

and a pastebin of the snippet of markets.txt that include multiple farmers markets in one town(Granville):

https://pastebin.com/cFdb7HZ5

Comment: honestly, you wouldn't really want to order these as much... since you can search by two things then you will want to get all the other elements right?

Why dont you just make each line a list of data in an overall list; something like `[i[0] for i in list if term in i]`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem! :D

The problem was that the dictionaries I was using didn't store multiples of the same value. This could be solved using a defaultdict(list) and appending lists. Then to navigate the nested lists, I made a separate method to search for values using similar to what Ironkey suggested. I also changed the way zip codes were retrieved from market tuples by using another defaultdict matching multiple unique addresses to zip codes.

Final fixed code that accounts for multiple markets in 1 zip code/town name.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
Dzcode_mtuples = defaultdict(list)
Dtowns_mtuples = defaultdict(list)
Dtowns_zcodes = defaultdict(list)
Daddress_zcodes = defaultdict(list)
a = set()
def read_markets(filename):
    """
    Read in the farmers market data from the file named filename and return 
    a tuple of two objects:
    1) A dictionary mapping zip codes to lists of farmers market tuples.
    2) A dictionary mapping towns to sets of zip codes.
    """
 
 
 
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            s = line.strip().split('#')
            #zip codes in a set
            a.add(s[4])

          #s[4] are zipcodes, s[3] are towns, s[:4] is state, name, address, city
            #dictionary mapping 1 zip code to multiple farmers markets tuples
            #dictionary mapping 1 town name to multiple farmers markets tuples
            #dictionary mapping towns to sets of zip codes
            #dictionary mapping unique addresses to zip codes
            mtuple = [s[:4]]
            
            Dzcode_mtuples[s[4]].append(mtuple)
            Dtowns_mtuples[s[3]].append(mtuple)
            Dtowns_zcodes[s[3]].append(a)
            Daddress_zcodes[s[2]].append(s[4])
           # print(market_name)
            #print(s[:4])
        return Dzcode_mtuples, Dtowns_mtuples
    
def search_nested(mylist, val):
            for i in range(len(mylist)):
                for j in range(len(mylist[i])):
            #print i,j
                    #print(mylist)
                    if mylist[i][j] == val:
                        return mylist[i]
            return str(val) + ' not found'
        
def list2string(s):  
    
    str1 = ""  
    
    #for element i in list s    transverse in the string 
    for i in s:  
        str1 += i   
    

    return str1  
 
 
def print_market(market):
    """
    Returns a human-readable string representing the farmers market tuple
    passed to the market parameter.
    """

    #input is market tuple
    name = market[1]
    address = market[2]
    city = market[3]
    state = market[0]
    
    #zcode is ['zipcode'] list from the dictionary that matched address to zcode. address is unique to each farmers market so its good to use to search
    
    zcode = (list(Daddress_zcodes.values())[list(Daddress_zcodes.keys()).index(market[2])]) 
    

    #the list2string method makes zcode a clean string
    final = name + "\n" + address + "\n" + city + ", " + state + " " + list2string(zcode)
    #print(final)
    return final
 #   print(b)
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # This main program first reads in the markets.txt once (using the function
    # from part (a)), and then asks the user repeatedly to enter a zip code or
    # a town name (in a while loop until the user types "quit").
 
    FILENAME = "markets.txt"
    c = 0

    try: 
        zip_to_market, town_to_zips = read_markets(FILENAME)
        while c < 1:
            u_in = input("enter zip code or town name: ")
            if u_in == "quit":
                c = 1
            else:
                #check if its a zip code
                if u_in.isdigit():
                    print("\nOk, I will look for farmers markets matching that zipcode \n")
                    askzip = str(u_in)
                    #list of all zipcodes
                    zlist = Dzcode_mtuples.keys()
                    #print(zlist)
                    #look for corresponding zipcode in dictionary that maps zipcodes to market tuples
                    if askzip in zlist:
                        out1 = Dzcode_mtuples.get(askzip)
                        for x in out1:
                            print(print_market(x[0]) + "\n")
                    else:
                        print('No corresponding farmers markets exist for that zipcode')
                

                #user input is town name
                else:
                    print("\nOk, I will look for farmers markets in that town \n")
                    asktown = str(u_in)
                    tlist = Dtowns_mtuples.keys()
                    if asktown in tlist:
                        #look for user input town in all the towns
                        out1 = Dtowns_mtuples.get(asktown)
                        #out1 is a list of mtuples that satisfy this
                        #print(out1[0][0])
                        for x in out1:
                            #print(Dzcode_mtuples.values())
                            #print(x[0])
                            print(print_market(x[0]) + "\n")

                    else:
                        print('No corresponding farmers markets exist for that town name')

 
 
 
    except (FileNotFoundError, IOError): 
        print("Error reading {}".format(FILENAME))
        

#testing things 
#read_markets("markets.txt")
#market = ['Wyoming', 'Wyoming Fresh Market', '121 W 15th Street', 'Cheyenne']
#print_market(market)
```